# Dual/Stacked switch available for 1 switch being a dimmer for the overhead LED and the other for the Bathroom fan/light on/off only?

Tags: bathroom, led, bathroom-fixtures

Situation I have is a dual/stacked switch in the bathroom. One of the switches is on/off for the vanity lights and the other is for the bathroom fan/light.

I changed my lighting to LED fixtures and would like to stick with the stacked switch if possible, but would like a dimmable option for the overhead and the bottom just and on/off for the combo fan/light.

I am not finding options for a dual/stack that seems to accomplish that. The ones I find seems to be for Incandescent and Halogen Bulbs, 300-Watt, Single-Pole, which could/will cause issues with the LED's not dimming properly or humming etc.

So essentially I am looking for a split switch with 150 watt top and 300 watt bottom split if possible. Please correct me if I am wrong in my thinking or if I am overlooking a product that is available.

For reference, this is the look I am hoping to stay with and not sliders or turn knobs etc.
[https://www.amazon.com/Lutron-Incandescent-300-Watt-Single-Pole-MA-L3L3-WH/dp/B0016P6JHG/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=double+dimmer+switch+for+led+lights&qid=1640297883&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0016P6JHG)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you not able to find the Lutron MA-L3S25 at all?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Lutron MA-L3S25 is listed for incandescent dimming. OP has LEDs.

Comment: What make/model of LED bulb/fixture are you using?

Comment: Lutron’s page says “current dual light controls are not rated for use with LED lighting.” I didn’t see a Leviton alternative. This reduces to a shopping question, but could you use a non-dimming dual switch with a smart LED bulb that can dim itself? That would force you to dim with an app or smart home device, so perhaps not ideal.

Comment: You may want to try that double stack switch with your LED’s. The possible problems are a glow when off, or limited dimming ability (they are brighter than you want at lowest setting) some of the newer LED’s do work with older style dimmers the ones I found that did work had a mechanical rotary dimmer when turned off it opened a switch so no glow at off but that will probably be the issue and the reason it is not listed for LED’s.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm looking for the same thing but can't find one. This seems like it should be a thing!